# Windows 7 unable to launch java control panel

Tags: windows-7, windows, java, console

whenever I click on java control panel, nothing happens.  I  did

```
C:\Windows\System32>control java.cpl
```

still nothing happens.
I installed Java 6 update 24(the latest update), did not help.
how do I fix this problem?

Comment: Do the symptoms continue if you try with a different user?

Answer (score 2):

I realise this is an old post but I have recently had this issue in a corporate environment when using MS EMET 5.2 and it was because DEP was enabled in EMET. Removing the tick from DEP in the EMET GUI returned the Java control panel.

Answer (score 2):

I had this problem before with jre6 u45 32bit. By coincidence i found this repeatable solution:
It works for me.

1. Open Display Settings.
2. Go to change ClearType-Text.
3. In the ClearType wizard enable and then disable the ClearType checkbox.
4. Click next.
5. Choose a textsaple that differentiates from the one marked by default
6. Repeat this in the rest of the steps of the wizard.
7. Click finish and close the wizard.
8. Try to open Java Control Panel.
9. It should now Open.

Answer (score 0):

Try opening "`C:\Program Files\Java\jre6\bin\javacpl.exe`" from an **elevated** command prompt (i.e. run as administrator.)

Comment: surprise, nothing happened, no error messages, nothing, nada

Comment: @user157195, do you have any javaw.exe processes showing up in Task Manager?

Comment: yes I have a few javaw.exe processes, they belong to other java procesess(netbean etc).  opening javacpl does not change the count.

Answer (score 0):

I once also had this problem with the exact symptoms.

The only operations that helped was to remove it using the *Add/Remove software* applet, reboot, delete the folder `C:\Program Files\Java` and then install it again.

This fixed it for me.

Answer (score -1):

Java Verify failure  unable to Configure Java Control Panel not opening ( Fix : )

Java Verify failure  unable to Configure Java Control Panel does not open ( Fix : ) 
this is a regular ( windows 7 bug related ) problem after successful installation of Java ( jre ) and fresh installation of Windows7 64bit or 32bit on my laptop or desktop.  what worked perfectly for me was setting  COMPATIBILITYMODE=WINDOWSNT  to make windows launch the JP2LAUNCHER.EXE  and  JAVAW.EXE  files properly.
jp2launcher.exe windowsNT compatibilty solves Java Verify failure problem at  https://www.java.com/en/download/installed.jsp
javaw.exe windowsNT compatibilty solves unable to open or Configure Java Control Panel problem.

```
*  search for JAVAW.EXE   inside  c:\program files   or  c:\program files (x86)
*  right-click mouse on  JAVAW   application icon logo
*  click  PROPERTIES
*  click  COMPATIBILITY
*  tick the checkbox at COMPATIBILITY MODE
*  choose  WINDOWS NT service pack
*  click APPLY or click OK
```

Now, the Configure Java Control Panel will start opening and working.

```
*  search for JP2LAUNCHER.EXE   inside  c:\program files   or  c:\program files (x86)
*  right-click mouse on  JP2LAUNCHER
*  click  PROPERTIES
*  click  COMPATIBILITY
*  tick the checkbox at COMPATIBILITY MODE
*  choose  WINDOWS NT service pack
*  click APPLY or click OK
```

Now, the Verify Java will be successful at  https://www.java.com/en/download/installed.jsp

if we find 2 or 3 versions of JP2LAUNCHER and JAVAW when we search, then we must repeat the above for all of them.

in the Configure Java Control Panel Advanced tab we can set "Do not check" certificate revocation and disable security verification.
and in the Security tab we may Edit Site List... for the Exception Site List  ( add URLs to  unblock sites )

Answer (score -1):

You can rename the folder `C:\Users\YourAccount\AppData\LocalLow\Sun` (Windows 7).

This solves not only the problem with frozen Java Control Panel, but also problems with Java cache and Java based programs that wouldn't work.

Comment: Welcome, please use code block to format file paths. The steps in your answer are not complete (i.e. rename the folder to what?). The question does not seem to be answering the problem (i.e. unable to launch Java control panel). Answer like this would benefit from some explanation of how it actually solves the problem.